# How to use FileChooser in gluon when platform is Desktop?

Tags: java, gluon, javafxports

I know that Gluon mobile can not use FileChooser.
But my question is that when I try to use PicturesService to loadImageFromGallery in Desktop and it is not working.
So I wonder to detect when platform is Desktop then use FileChooser.
But just can't get stage?
Can you help to how to solve it?

```
FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage);
                                       ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the [source code](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down/src/11c36e187921b2eac4a3d518cc00ad9108cab89f/plugins/plugin-pictures/?at=default) for the Pictures service in Charm Down, there is no `DesktopPicturesService` implemented (yet).

This means that the call to `service.loadImageFromGallery()`:

```
Services.get(PicturesService.class).ifPresent(service -> service.loadImageFromGallery());
```

won't be done if you are running on Desktop.

A quick solution is detecting that you are running on Desktop, and call the FileChooser directly, else use the pictures service:

```
if (Platform.isDesktop()) {
    FileChooser...
} else {
    Services.get(PicturesService.class).ifPresent(service -> service.loadImageFromGallery());
}
```

For a better integration, nothing prevents you from adding the missing DesktopPicturesService implementation to your project, and include a `FileChooser`, to be able to load a picture in your application.

For that you just need to:

- add the `pictures` plugin to the list of services in `DownConfig` (build.gradle)
- add to the `Desktop/Java Packages` folder the following package: `com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins.desktop`
- add the class `DesktopPicturesService` to that package, that implements `PicturesService`, and implement the required methods:

`DesktopPicturesService.java`

```
public class DesktopPicturesService implements PicturesService {

    @Override
    public Optional<Image> takePhoto(boolean savePhoto) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Image> loadImageFromGallery() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

}
```

- Now add the FileChooser:

This is a simple implementation:

```
@Override
public Optional<Image> loadImageFromGallery() {
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilterJPG = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("JPG files (*.jpg)", "*.JPG");
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(extFilterJPG);

    try {
        File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (file != null) {
            Image image = new Image(new FileInputStream(file));
            return Optional.ofNullable(image);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {}
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

About the `stage` argument, you can set it to null, or get it from the `MobileApplication` instance:

```
Stage stage = MobileApplication.getInstance().getView().getScene().getWindow();
```

- Finally, use your service in your application.

Add an `ImageView` and call the service:

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
Services.get(PicturesService.class).ifPresent(pictures -> {
    pictures.loadImageFromGallery().ifPresent(imageView::setImage);
});
```

This will work now on both desktop and mobile devices.

As an extra, you could also implement the `takePhoto` method, accessing the [webCam](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/tree/master/webcam-capture-examples/webcam-capture-javafx) of your desktop machine, if exists...